# bash: how to list a leaf directory in the unknown path?

Tags: bash, basename

I have multiple directories that in turn contain subdirectories. Example:

```
company_a/raw/2020/12
```

The value of the first directory (`company_a` in the sample above) is variable, but always with a pattern "`word_letter`"

The value of the second directory `raw` is immutable

The values of the last two directories (`/2020/12` in the sample above) are variable.

My purpose is to extract the size of each leaf subdirectory (given the sample path above, the leaf subdir would be `12/`) using a `for` loop.

Is there some kind of reverse `basename` utility which would allow me to list the entire path, using `company_x/` dir as the root dir? Because if I want to extract directories' size, first I need to figure out how to list the last directories in the path.

A sample tree for reference:

```
$ tree company_b
tree company_b
└── raw
    └── 2020
        ├── 05
        │   └── data.raw
        ├── 06
        │   └── data.raw
        ├── 07
        │   └── data.raw
        └── 08
            └── data.raw

6 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: reverse `basename`? probably `realpath`. for directory size use `du` with depth option. your goal is very unclear to me

Answer (score 3):

The `du` command does this very well using wildcards.

```
du -h */raw/*/*
```

Output:

```
80K company_b/raw/2021/02
80K company_b/raw/2021/05
80K company_b/raw/2021/04
80K company_b/raw/2021/01
80K company_b/raw/2021/03
```

Comment: The following commands were used to create the toy example: `mkdir -p company_b/raw/2021/{01..05}; for dir in */raw/2021/*; do tr -dc \047[:alnum:]\047 </dev/urandom | head -c3000 > $dir/raw.txt; done`